# Show total viewed

Tags: entries

I am using the [EntryCount](https://www.putyourlightson.net/craft-entry-count) which count the entry and total view of an entry and I want to show total view of entries of a particular user.
Something like:

```
User XYZ:
Entries: ABC(10 View) + DEF(20 View) + GHI(10 View) = 40 View (Total).

User MNO:
Entries: ABC(10 View) + DEF(10 View) + GHI(10 View) = 30 View (Total).
```

I just want to show this:

```
'XYZ':40(View) and 'MNO': 30(View).
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Never used the plugin, but after glancing thought the source code, I don't think it's possible given its current implementation without modifications.

Currently it's tracking entry counts on a global basis and not a per-user basis.